# mysql_fetch_array() error when running page online

Tags: php, mysql

When i run my website local using IIS7 it runs fine but now i have uploaded it to a webhost i get this error from the menu part of the page.

Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /srv/disk13/1572246/www/iansdrivingschool.atspace.cc/includes/menulearner.php on line 8

```
<?php
    include("includes/connect.php"); 

   // get value of id that sent from address bar
   $id=$_GET['id'];

   $sql="SELECT * FROM 'apply' WHERE id =".$id;
   $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<!--navigation menu-->
<div id="navcontainer">
    <ul id="navlist">
        <li><a href="prices.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="profile_update.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Edit Profile</a> </li>
        <li><a href="includes/logout-activation.php">Log Out</a>
    </ul>
</div>

<?php
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging with var_dump or print_r? What do you get?

Comment: No - Im not sure how to do that again.

Comment: Include `var_dump($row); break;` just after `$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);` then share the output.

Comment: Do it like this: `print_r(mysql_fetch_array($result));`

Comment: to share the output would i just <?php echo $row ?>

Comment: No.. Just the print_r or var_dump will do...

Comment: ok getting a small bit lost. Could someone show me where whats to go where please.

Comment: ok with var_dump($row); i get bool(False) under the error

Answer (score 0):

Please fix:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM apply WHERE id = ".(int)$id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use backticks instead of quotes in table names. Use the revised code -

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `apply` WHERE id = $id";
```

You can also do it without the usage of backticks. But reserved keywords like `FROM`,`TO`,`DATE`etc.. must be escaped using backticks. Otherwise, your code without quotes will also work ->

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM apply WHERE id = $id";
```

**EDIT :**  Also, you are rendering the data received from mysql the wrong way. Use ->

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<!--navigation menu-->
<div id="navcontainer">
    <ul id="navlist">
        <li><a href="prices.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="profile_update.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Edit Profile</a>         </li>
        <li><a href="includes/logout-activation.php">Log Out</a>
    </ul>
</div><?php
} ?>
```

Comment: when i change the $sql line nothing changes with the error message

Comment: @DerekCurdie, put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your page to know what the error is.

Comment: done and now getting "Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /srv/disk13/1572246/www/iansdrivingschool.atspace.cc/includes/menulearner.php on line 9 bool(false)"

Comment: @DerekCurdie, updated the answer. Did not saw that. You must handle the data within a while loop `while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){...}` and not `$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);`. That is both a syntax error as well as a logical error to some extent. Mysql returns you many columns and not just one column. But in your case, only one column is returned. But you must use a loop to let get your data anyway.

Comment: @DerekCurdie, please go through the examples at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php . It might help you.

Answer (score 0):

connect your php in your db

set in your php file top

```
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost";


$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("android_app",$dbhandle)
  or die("Could not select DB");
```

but set your database configuration username password and database name

and chaneg your query string to

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM 'apply' WHERE id =".$id;
```

Comment: ive added a connect file to the page.

Comment: change to $sql="SELECT * FROM 'apply' WHERE id =".$id; your query strin

Answer (score 0):

Looked at the database and forgot i changed the table name to lessons and not apply - thank you all for your help.